___ an average day, it often takes me 30 minutes to get to work and back. On or In?

I don't often go anywhere except for work, and ___ an average day, it often takes me 30 minutes to get there and back.

I feel like both are correct here, aren't they? Is there any difference between them?

"On" is the correct prep. But "on an average day" and "often" don't go well together. I would drop one or the other.

going somewhere for work and to work are not the same thing.

@user1176409 I would steer well away with "this website" and double-check any article written by Marcus Froland especially after he asserted There was a time when “in average” was commonly used, but it has gradually lost favor among native speakers and language professionals. Today, “on average” is the established norm, and the usage of “in average” is considered a common mistake.  Absolutely wrong: 1. "But even in average or below-average years for hurricanes, there is still a chance that a powerful storm will make landfall."


which found that the difference in average rates between home buyers who pay discount points and those who don’t is very small.  3. But in recent years, the state has also seen long-term declines in average annual rainfall, thinner cloud cover and drought induced by climbing temperatures. NYT (2023/24)



I don't often go anywhere except for work, and ___ an average day, it often takes me 30 minutes to get there and back.

Wrong:

In an average day, it often takes me 30 minutes to get to work and back.

Better:

On an average day, it often takes me 30 minutes to get to work and back.

Even better, because the filler/redundancy has been cut out:

On an average day, it takes me 30 minutes to get to work and back.
It often takes me 30 minutes to get to work and back.

Best, because it's finally clear that we are referring to a mathematical average (30 mins) rather than a usual/routine/ordinary/"average" day:

On average, it takes me 30 minutes to get to work and back.



I don't often go anywhere except for work

This sentence isn't quite correct either, because "anywhere" and "for work" aren't parallel constructions. Correction (choose the latter if it's a flexible work environment):

I don't often go anywhere except to work.
I don't often go out unless it's for work.

